# Merging two dictionaries into a resultant dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge

I'm trying to merge two lists that I have.

```
gpbdict = dict(zip(namesb, GPB))
>>> {'1': True, '3': True, '2': True, '5': True, '4': True, '7': True, '6': True, '8': True}
gpadict = dict(zip(namesa, GPA))
>>> {'11': True, '10': True, '13': True, '12': True, '15': True, '14': True, '16': True, '9': True}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be as simple as just:

```
 json.loads(gpadict + gpbdict)
```

or

```
gpa_gpb = [gpadict, gpbdict]
print json.dumps(gpa_gpb, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Only the later will produce a result with two separate lists:

```
>>>[
>>>  {
>>>    "10": true,
>>>    "11": true,
>>>    "12": true,
>>>    "13": true,
>>>    "14": true,
>>>    "15": true,
>>>    "16": true,
>>>    "9": true
>>>  },
>>>  {
>>>    "1": true,
>>>    "2": true,
>>>    "3": true,
>>>    "4": true,
>>>    "5": true,
>>>    "6": true,
>>>    "7": true,
>>>    "8": true
>>>  }
>>>]
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: You can easy find answer to this question thru google. Veeeeery easy. Also you should learn more about Python terms.

Comment: @anandtripathi Caution! `update` method on dictionaries does *not* return anything. But the essence of your comment is true and valid.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON or lists.

Comment: I realised that  and we cannot edit the comment so i had to delete that @MariusSiuram sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 3):

You are doing some strange stuff.

First of all, you want to merge Python objects, don't you? And why and how? Both `gpbdict` and `gpbadict` are dictionaries (not `list`) so your question is not very specific. And `json.loads` is expected to receive a string (a JSON) **not** a Python object. So, maybe you simply want:

```
gpbadict = dict(zip(namesb + namesa, GPB + GPA))
```

Note that the operator `+` works ok with lists, but not with dictionaries.

If you want to merge dictionaries, on the other hand, you could use the `update`:

```
gpadict.update(gpbdict)
```

And that will effectively merge the dictionary: `gpadict` will become the combination of both `gpadict` (the starting one) and `gpbdict`. If there are repeteated keys, they will be overwritten.

And in the whole question I could not find any real reference to JSON. I am missing something?